# jstree open_node not working on child nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

When my checkbox jstree has finished loading, I wish to pre open the last opened nodes (**not** `select_node`). The `open_node` function only seems to work on the top most parent level nodes. I even tried iterating through the node and calling `open_node` and it still doesn't work. I have the following:

```
// Create instance for checkbox jstree.
$(function () {
    $('#myTree').jstree({
        "core": {
            "themes": {
                'name': 'default',
                "variant": "small",
                "icons": false
            },
        },
        "checkbox": {
            "keep_selected_style": false,
            "three_state": false,
        },
        "plugins": ["checkbox"]
    });
});

$("#myTree").bind('ready.jstree', function (event, data) {
    var $tree = $(this);
    $($tree.jstree().get_json($tree, {
        "flat": true
    })).each(function (index, value) {
        // lastOpenedNode.value contains the id of the last opened node
        if ( nodeWasLastOpened(this.id) == true)
            // ONLY OPENS TOP MOST PARENT NODES
            $("#myTree").jstree().open_node(this.id);
    })
});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a private method you could use for that, `_open_to`, that will open all nodes down to the one you want to be shown. Check code below and demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/swnm9mx4/).

```
 $("#myTree").jstree()._open_to( lastOpenedNode.value );
```

or

```
if ( nodeWasLastOpened(this.id) )
     $("#myTree").jstree()._open_to( this.id );
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have phrased my question better (made edit above). I'm actually wish to open more than one node. This works great, but only works once.

Comment: I found out what my issue was. I initially stored the node ids as strings and then was passing it to the `open_node` function. Once I converted it to an `int`, the function works perfectly. Thank you.